# Refresh input text box with new string every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've searched on here and other places (about 15 other forums...yes I kept count) as well and I can't seem to find any previous posts that match what is below. Either that or I didn't search hard enough....

What I'm trying to do: Everytime someone presses the submit button I want the `<input type="text" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="">` to have a new random string (new id) so that way each time someone presses submit the id is not a replica of the previous as I'm using such ID (not the automated ID by database) to identify these comments.

What I currently have `<input type="text" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="<?php $length = 18; $randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length); echo $randomString;?>">`

That broken down is basically this

```
<?php 
$length = 18;
$randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length); 
echo $randomString;
?>
```

Gives me an 18 character string like this (BknmexSFAgP7pjsUIo).

So all in all I just want it so that every single time someone presses submit, the input box gives me a new ID, I've tried using several methods but none seem to do the trick....

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: why not use GUID ?

Comment: The method I use is not the problem, I need a new ID in the input box every single time the Submit button is posted. Even if I used GUID I would need to generate a new ID either way. Thank you for your reply though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after many many many.....okay after A LOT of searching, I finally found my answer. Now this is my own modified code but I'm going to post it in case anyone else would need help with this.

I have this refreshing every 1 second so that way if someone decided to comment right after they've already posted a comment, the previous comment doesn't have the same id as the current....yea I know that did not make sense, but then again it did. :/

```
<textarea id="comment_id"></textarea>

var myCommentID = setInterval(generateCommentID, 1000);
function generateCommentID() {
    var comment = "0123456789-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var result = "", rand;
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * comment.length);
            result += comment.charAt(rand);
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("comment_id").innerHTML = result;
}
```

Original code is from [this sexy fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3VSs/64/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it dynamically without loading your page , you should do it with ajax.

```
$.ajax({
                url: "url to your php  goes here",
                  },
                success: function (data) {
                $('#comment_id').val() = data;
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Doesn't work and I actually tried something like this before I posted my question on here. Thank you for your reply though.